# why？Fail with error 'Pancake: OVERFLOW'

Tags: contract-development, pancakeswap

I can't finish my pool. The [Transaction Details page](https://bscscan.com/tx/0x018c310e66238084647c8ae1055fbcbce0ab74915e09cd235c09d5a64ce14dfc) is showing error:

> Fail with error 'Pancake: OVERFLOW'

What can I do?

Comment: try to add more information please on what steps you did ... until this error

Comment: Hi cnbluelsf! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! Please add the code of the contract.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.